# How to get data from model in node express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, backend

I'm new to MERN and stackoverflow.
I want to get all data from mongodb database. But when I try it through postman, It shows following error.

[image]

Here is my Model.js file
**Model.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    code: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    passMark: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    lic: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    subjects: [
        { 
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            required: false, 
            ref: 'Subjects' 
        }
    ]
};

const Model= mongoose.model("Model",Schema);

module.exports = Model;
```

Here is my router.js file
**Router.js**

```
const Model= require("../models/Model");
const route = require("express").Router();

route.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    Model.find()
   .exec((err, items)=>{
        if(!err){
            return res.json({items: items})
        }
    })
});
```

Someone can help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you add middleware to your server to parse json?  Did you add `app.use(express.json())`?  Or something like that?  Otherwise, you'd have trouble.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `express.json()` is used to parse the incoming req.body. It's empty here, OP isn't using it.

Comment: @isaacsan123 I used it.

Comment: @JeremyThille I used it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a blind guess, but I believe the error occurs because `Model.find()` does not return JSON data. It returns a collection of Mongoose objects, with extra methods like `.save()`. If you want pure JSON out of Mongo, add `.lean()` :

```
route.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    Model.find().lean()
   .exec((err, items)=>{
        if(!err){
            return res.json({items: items})
        }
    })
});
```

Pro tip, same thing using the async/await syntax :

```
route.get("/", async (req,res)=>{
   try{
       const items = await Model.find().lean().exec(); // .exec() returns a true Promise
       res.json({items});
   } catch(err) {
      res.status(500).end(err)
   }
});
```